# How do I print CD Cover in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, printing, cd

I have and HP Officejet 6500 Wireless printer and I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 32bit. I want to print CD covers, what kind of software can i use to do that? I already tried glables, Gimp, and Image viewer.

Answer (score 4):

The default cd-burn application in Ubuntu, called Brasero, actually has a build-in CV Cover printer.

- Launch brasero
- Select any of the project types
- Click on the menu 'extra'
- Select 'CD Cover Printer'

It will fill the cover with the data from the project. For music this would be the tracklisting. For files this would be the file-listing, etc.

Comment: Ralf: how do i do it Brasero?

Comment: I've updated the description of my answer a little. I hope it's clear now!

Answer (score 2):

There's also Kover, disc-cover, and CDcover that might work for you.  They're all in the repos.

Answer (score 1):

What was the problem with glabels ? Any specific feature you're looking for ?

You could also try Koverartist